# Digitalizing precipitation data from the image of weather map

Tags: meteorology, precipitation, software, netcdf

I have a set of very old precipitation anomaly maps, from 1995-2006 for Brazil. The data of these maps, is to the best of my knowlegde, lost.

I would like to have them digitalized, ie, to NetCDF or another similar gridded format. Is there any tools recommendend for this job?

The figure below is a recent plot, similar to my files.

[image: similar plot]

Comment: Are you sure the data is lost? Have you checked the standard data sources?

Comment: Just three points to remember when it comes to interpretation: In arid to semi-arid areas the spottiness of the rainfall distribution doesn't average out on any useful time-scale, and certainly not over an 11 year time-series. Secondly, in mountainous areas like the Andes the local physiographic effects totally eclipse the true regional variation. Thirdly, the map you show looks suspiciously as if it has been generated by a 'contour package', which is often totally misleading because it treats the rainfall in a small rain-guage as an areal maximum or minimum  - which it isn't!.

Comment: @BarryCarter One can always be surer, but I have put some hours in it and could not find data at this resolution going back to 1995.

Comment: Fair enough. I take it https://climatedataguide.ucar.edu/climate-data/cpc-unified-gauge-based-analysis-global-daily-precipitation and things like http://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/CPC_UNI_PRCP/GAUGE_GLB/V1.0/1985/ were unhelpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the image to NetCDF data using `gdal_translate`. The command line looks something like:

```
gdal_translate -ot Int16 -of netCDF jpeg_filename nc_filename
```

You can use ncl example: [click here](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/Scripts/topo_9.ncl)